# How to backup the application's database to the Google servers

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which will do the backup  of Application's database to the 
Google servers and restores the data after reinstalling the application.

I didn't find any reference to do this task. and one more thing, i tried the application given in the Android SDK, which is working only with the Shell commands but not by running the application.

Could any body is having an idea how to do the backup and restoring of the Application's database data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this feature was added in Android 2.2

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Comment: There is also a sample in the SDK http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/index.html

Comment: But that sample is not working to do the Backup using the application. I can able to run that application through command line and is working fine. and that to in that application he has not mentioned how to do the Application's database backup. Any one got succeeded  in doing Backup through program??

Comment: Through program also its working but it takes time to backup the data.